# Filter multi-table inheritance in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to make a dynamic filter for multi-table inheritance.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name ...

class Product1(Product):
    color ...

class Product2(Product):
    length ...
    tags = ManyToManyField('tags.Tag')
```

How to filter so as not to cause an exception "missing field"?

```
Product.objects.filter(***__color='11', ***__length='300', **__tags__pk__in=[1, 2])
```

Comment: I don't think you will able to do that. `Prodct` models does not know fields added by derived class, so it will raise those errors.

Comment: Okay, but you can find all the unique subclasses in a query? `Product.objects.all()` -> fine `[<class Product 1>, <class Product 2>]`; `Product.objects.filter(name='11')` -> fine `[<class Product 1>`;

Answer (score 0):

Use model names as prefixes like this:

```
Product.objects.filter(product1__color='11', product2__length='300', product2__tags__pk__in=[1, 2])
```

Comment: Easy %) ... but Product or product1 or product2 ... Product.objects.filter(product1__color='11', product2__length='300') -> Product2 missing field "color" -> error

Comment: Can you post a full traceback?